# how can i configure port in emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run react-native app but after buil successfull terminal says somthing like this

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

```
Total time: 9.967 secs
Running c:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (c:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell
am start -n com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }
Done in 15.61s.
```

In the emulator says

```
The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"originModulePath":"C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js","targetModuleName":"AccessibilityInfo","message":"Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ModuleResolution.js:167:1306)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ResolutionRequest.js:80:16)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph.js:237:485)\n    at Object.resolve (C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\lib\\transformHelpers.js:116:25)\n    at dependencies.map.result (C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:298:29)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at resolveDependencies (C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:294:16)\n    at C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:159:33\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at step (C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:239:307)"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:285
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:37
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:163
execute
    RealCall.java:153
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636
run
    Thread.java:764
```

Is there any way to fix this ??

Comment: Have you tried the solution the error message is telling you: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968?

Comment: yes i did try to run adb emulator-5554 reverse tcp: 8081 tcp: 8081

Comment: @JaviMollá why did you provided this link i think this has nothing to do with my question. tell me if i am wrong

Comment: It's in what the emulator says, as you posted: Body:
{"originModulePath":"C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js","targetModuleName":"AccessibilityInfo","message":"Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\react-native\\awesomeproject\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native...

Comment: are you using a Kit-Kat version?

Comment: no oreo version

Answer (score 0):

react-native is broken in 0.56 for windows.
downgrade to 0.55.4

after creating a project with 0.56, downgrade to 0.55.4.

related issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953

Comment: it still gives the error something different from previous

Comment: The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"type":"InternalError","errors":[],"message":"Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:266

Comment: see the console window of Metro for the error, probably it's just some javascript typo.

Comment: i don't think so i have just created this app using create-react-native i haven't changed any single word in it yet.

Comment: didn't know you are using expo, sorry, i was using a project created by "react-native init"... you can check the latest react-native now: version 0.57